# theme in ggplot not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, ggplot2, python-ggplot

Creating a bar plot using ggplot in python

```
plot_bar = ggplot(df_aggr , aes( x='Industry',weight='Brand_Value'))           
print plot_bar + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

This gives[image]

However, when trying to vertically align the xtick labels(Industry field) using theme(axis_text_x = element_text(angle= 90),it doesn't work rather give the beginning of the bar as value.

```
 plot_bar = ggplot(df_aggr , aes( x='Industry',weight='Brand_Value'))
 print plot_bar + geom_bar(stat='identity') +theme( axis_text_x = element_text(angle=90))
```

[image]

How to get the Industry x tick labels vertically aligned on x axis ?

Comment: `.` works in R code.`_` works in python